# Glide doesn't fire any result and stuck loading

Tags: android-glide

I'm using glide to load images. But When loading images in activities, Glide simply will not load an image. But also doesnt run results (Don't run failed or success). But when I use it in Fragment and recyclerview It works.

My code:

```
Glide.with(CommentActivity.this).load(imageurl).dontAnimate().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            imageurl="";
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            GenelUtil.ToastLong(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.failedtoloadimage));
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            imageType="url";
            imagelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    }).into(commentimage);
```

How to fix this?